# How to override read-only property from Objective-C in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

This is how it is defined in objective-c:

```
@interface AFHTTPRequestOperation : AFURLConnectionOperation

@property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) id responseObject;
```

How to assign sth to this property?

I would like to mock this property for later usage. So I need there my own `responseObject` overriden in Swift. Any ideas how to do this? I can subclass, extend or whatever. The only thing is it must by type of `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

```
class MyRequestOperation: AFHTTPRequestOperation {

    override var responseObject: [String: AnyObject]
}
```

It produces an error:

> `Getter for responseObject with Objective-C selector responseObject conflicts with getter for responseObject from superclass AHTTPRequestOperation with the same Objective-C selector`

Comment: `override let responseObject = …`?

Comment: then try without the initialization part: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005259/objective-c-setter-overriding-in-swift)

Comment: I mean exactly what I wrote. Read the question I linked.

Comment: As property type in superclass is declared as `id` in swift version you should probably use AnyObject, not any stricter type

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant - example from question is not about `read-only` property

Comment: @Vladimir, it doesn't work... The same error as I wrote in question

Comment: It is good to  have immutable readonly property. Create some method that creates a new object with modified property like [NSString stringByAppendingString:] which does not return the same string, but does some change on the original value or simply create a method inside the class to change the attribute.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk if you change `var` to `let`, it will represent a read-only property.

Answer (score 19):

So, the answer is simple as @Atul Mishra said:

```
class MyRequestOperation: AFHTTPRequestOperation {

    var myOverridenResponseObject: AnyObject?

    override var responseObject: AnyObject? {

        get {
            return myOverridenResponseObject
        }

        set {
            myOverridenResponseObject = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can present an inherited read-only property as a read-write property by providing both a getter and a setter in your subclass property override.but however you cannot provide an inherited read-write property as read-only property.
for better clarification refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-XID_300