# BOOL is incompatible with Bool in Swift 4.1

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift4.1

When overriding in a Swift subclass of an Objective-C class, I get a message saying:

> Property type 'BOOL' (aka 'bool') is incompatible with type 'Boolean' (aka 'unsigned char') inherited from 'ChildClass'

I tried to use Other Boolean types but it won't work.

Any idea how to properly override an Objc BOOL in Swift

**Swift code (subclass):**

```
override var myVar: Bool {
    get {
        return something ? true : myVar
    }
    set {
        myVar = newValue
    }
}
```

**Objc Parent Declaration:**

```
@property(atomic) Boolean isLoading;
```

**Swift bridging header where the warning appear:**

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC6Module30ChildClass")
@interface ChildClass : ParentClass
@property (nonatomic) BOOL myVar; //<----- Here 
@end
```

Comment: as? Bool - didn't works too?

Comment: @SergeyHleb Sorry I was'nt so clear. I added the code to disambiguate it. The issue is in the declaration of the bridging header

Comment: are you actually using/overriding the `isLoading` variable?

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005259/objective-c-setter-overriding-in-swift) can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ObjC BOOL and bool are not the same (BOOL is a signed char, whereas bool - aka C bool- is an unsigned char). Boolean is typedef to unsigned char as well, so is a C bool.
Can you change your objC property to BOOL?
if not, then use the swift type 'CBool'.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html

Comment: If I change the `Swift` type then it complain about incompatibilities with `bool`. Indeed, Using `BOOL` in the Objc parent did the trick. I'm so used to using only `BOOL` in objc I did'nt even noticed the parent had a different type